# How to save list of dicts as CSV and keep keys in order?

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of dicts and need to save them as CSV. The first line would be header listing field names.

Fields order should be the same as in header. The problem is that some fields are optional and some dicts don't contain them. Other problem is that python don't iterate dict keys in order they are defined.

```
import csv
import sys

fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'city']

dicts = [
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "city": "New York",
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Agent",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "city": "Matrix",
    },
]

csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

csv_writer.writerow(fields)

for obj in dicts:
    # fields order mismatch
    csv_writer.writerow(obj.values())
```

This would produce CSV rows that don't match header.

```
first_name, last_name, city
New York,   John,      Doe
Matrix,     Agent,     Smith
```

I could manually sort fields and check for missing items, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution to output dict values into CSV in predefined order?

Comment: What Python version are you using? That seems to be caused by the fact that  dictionaries do NOT preserve key order on Python versions prior to 3.6.

Comment: You can do it by changing line: `csv_writer.writerow([ obj[key] for key in fields ])`

Comment: Using python 2.7

Comment: @aminrd, that will not solve the problem because the Python version used does not preserve dictionaries key order. alex2007v posted the right answer.

Comment: @accdias That's why I am reading the orders from `fields` list!

Comment: Oh! Now I see it. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DictWriter (also you have a typo in `fieldnames` list: fi***sr***t_name instead of fi***rs***t_name):

```
import csv
import sys

fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'city']

dicts = [
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "city": "New York",
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Agent",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "city": "Matrix",
    },
]
writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=fieldnames)

writer.writeheader()
for row in dicts:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the specific problem in the question. However, on a more practical note: (1) latest versions of Python (3.6+) use ordered dicts as standard, and (2) this stuff is always easier if you use Pandas.

Comment: @ajrwhite, There is no reason in promote pandas for such a simple task when the standard library already has a `csv` module that solves the problem.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that this problem, in a practical setting, wouldn’t have additional facets that brought pandas functionality into play. I was just talking in practical, real-world terms - of course csv library is fine for the example problem as it is presented.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great that it utilizes python standard library `csv`. I'm just putting my answer here (using `pandas` approach) in case it may help someone.

```
In [12]: import pandas as pd

In [13]: dicts = [ 
    ...:     { 
    ...:         "first_name": "John", 
    ...:         "last_name": "Doe", 
    ...:         "city": "New York", 
    ...:     }, 
    ...:     { 
    ...:         "first_name": "Agent", 
    ...:         "last_name": "Smith", 
    ...:         "city": "Matrix", 
    ...:     }, 
    ...: ]                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [14]: df = pd.DataFrame(dicts)                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [15]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[15]: 
  first_name last_name      city
0       John       Doe  New York
1      Agent     Smith    Matrix

In [16]: df.to_csv("/path/to/save", index=False) # if you want to save
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's overkill for such a simple task: `sys.getsizeof(pd.DataFrame) == 1064` and `sys.getsizeof(csv.writer) == 80`.

Comment: @accdias Agreed, that's why I said that the accepted answer is great to use `csv`. But I think it's useful to put in here in case someone needed `pandas` solution to take advantage of easy data manipulation, etc.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm also a big fan of pandas BTW.